# What to do with pid files in a docker container

Tags: docker, pid, tmpfs

My containers aren't starting up on the second run because a pid file has been left behind in /var/run/.

I'm thinking of mounting /var/run/ on tmpfs is the way forward but that requires the container be run -privileged.

Is there a better way to deal with pid (and other temporary) files?

Comment: if you just want to remove a file, see `docker exec` something like `docker exec -it container_id rm file` the docc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for something more self sustaining.

Comment: Maybe you should look why you have pid files left behind. That's not normal :(